# Weird output of [97,98].map(String.fromCharCode)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

this works as expected

```
[97,98].map(function(x){String.fromCharCode(x)})
// [ 'a', 'b' ]
```

but the output is following line is unexpected

```
[97,98].map(String.fromCharCode)
// [ 'a\u0000\u0000', 'b\u0001\u0000' ]
```

Comment: The first one returns me `[undefined, undefined]` and the second one `["a", "b"]` in the Chrome console, where did you test ?

Comment: @Calvein firefox gives `["a\x00\x00", "b\x01\x00"]`, chrome gives `["a", "b"]` both give the same but chrome just doesn't print control characters

Comment: I used `JSON.stringify` to ensure the output showed me the control characters.

Comment: @Calvein it was tested in the coffeescript REPL, I forgot the `return` statement when translate it to javascript..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`String.fromCharCode` can accept a variable length of arguments, and treats each one as a character code to build a string `arguments.length` characters long.

`map` passes several arguments to the inner function. The first, obviously, is the value of the current item. The second is the index in the array, which is where the `\u0000` and `\u0001` come from (add more character codes and you get `\u0002`, `\u0003`...). The third argument is a reference to the array that is being traversed, which is converted to the number `0`.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

EDIT much, much later: An alternative approach:

```
String.fromCharCode.apply(String, [97,98]);
// [ 'a', 'b' ]
```

Comment: The article [A JavaScript Optional Argument Hazard](http://www.wirfs-brock.com/allen/posts/166) explores what is going on in situations like this.

Answer (score 0):

```
       a2 = [97,98].map(function(x){return String.fromCharCode(x)});
       alert(a2);
       a2 = [97,98].map(String.fromCharCode);
       alert(a2);
```

both alert "a,b" for Firefox13 on Linux. the first function was missing a return statement.