# Is a constructor a valid function for map()

Tags: javascript

I get this surprising (for me) result on my browsers:

```
> [104, 105, 115, 32, 105, 115, 32, 97, 32].map(String.fromCharCode);
["h", "i", "s", " ", "i", "s", " ", "a", " "]
> [104, 105, 115, 32, 105, 115, 32, 97, 32, 115].map(String.fromCharCode);
["h", "i", "s", " ", "i", "s", " ", "a", " ", "s    "]
```

(115 gives "s" for the first 2 occurrences, but a 3rd one gives something else)

It seems to work if I wrap it in another function:

```
> [104, 105, 115, 32, 105, 115, 32, 97, 32, 115].map(function(x) { return String.fromCharCode(x);});
["h", "i", "s", " ", "i", "s", " ", "a", " ", "s"]
```

Is this an implementation bug ? Else, can you point me to the relevant docs that explain this behaviour ?

Comment: As part of basic debugging, you should have checked to see if it still happened if you used a letter other than `s` ;)

Comment: Better way: `String.fromCharCode.apply(String,[104, 105, 115, 32, 105, 115, 32, 97, 32, 115]);`

Comment: I did, this was just an example. But since I did not understand what was going on, I had trouble simplifying it more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot pass [String.fromCharCode()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode) directly to [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), because `map()` will invoke it with *three* arguments (the current element, its index and the array itself).

In other words, the code:

```
[42].map(String.fromCharCode);
```

Will invoke `fromCharCode()` as:

```
String.fromCharCode(42, 0, [42]);
```

Since `fromCharCode()` processes all its arguments, this does not give the results you're looking for.

Comment: To be specific, the indexes from 0 to 8 produce invisible results, but index 9 is a tab, the first visible character. The third argument results in NUL, which is again not visible. Further investigation: `result[0].length` is three :)

Comment: See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11363526/weird-output-of-97-98-mapstring-fromcharcode

Comment: @rjdown: Your first link is already in the answer. The second is a good find however. The question is a dupe.

Comment: @rjdown, thanks for finding it :)

Comment: @MattBurland I don't even remember posting that answer XD

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol: What? Over 6,000 answers and you forgot one? Shocking. ;)

Comment: Thanks. I thought naively that map took only the value as argument.

Answer (score 0):

You problem is very similar to what happens if you do something like this:

```
["1", "2", "3"].map(parseInt);
```

See the discussion on [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) headed **Tricky use case** and the linked [blog post](http://www.wirfs-brock.com/allen/posts/166).

The problem is that the `array.map` function will pass 3 arguments to the callback `currentValue`, `index` and `array`. This isn't a problem if your actual callback only takes one argument (like when you wrap it in an anonymous function) because the other two will be ignored. But [fromCharCode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode) actually takes a sequence of numbers, so it will try and do something with the extra two arguments leading to confusing behavior.

In short, your callback for `.map` should either take only 1 argument. Or else it better know how to handle the other two.